# Gyro drifting by time

Tags: statistics, physics

I'm want to use a gyro which gives rotational velocity and to integrate it to get the angle. 
I was told that this can't be done due to the problem of drift. I was trying to understand why is this happening, if the error is normally disturbed shouldn't it eliminate it self? 
Thanks